# How to sort data using dropdown in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two functional components Dropdown, DisplayData and importing both in App.js.
I need to sort the record based on the selection from dropdown and DisplayData.

Dropdow.jsx

```
const DropDown = ()=>{
return (
    <>
    <select>
        <option value="lowtohigh">Age: Low to High </option>
        <option value="hightolow">Age: High to Low </option>
    </select>
    </>
)}
export default DropDown;
```

DisplayData.jsx

```
const DisplayData = ()=> {

const record = [
    {
        SR : 1,
        Name : 'Aakash',
        Age : 25
    },
    {
        SR : 4,
        Name : 'Zahir',
        Age : 32
    },
    {
        SR : 3,
        Name : 'Mohan',
        Age : 23
    },
    {
        SR : 2,
        Name : 'Parul',
        Age : 42
    },
    {
        SR : 9,
        Name : 'Himanshu',
        Age : 18
    },
];

return (
    <>
    <table>
        {record.map((rec,index)=>{
            return (
    
    <tr key={index}>
    <td>
     {rec.SR}
    </td>
    <td>
    {rec.Name}
    </td>
    <td>
   {rec.Age}
    </td>
</tr>
            )}) }
       
    </table>
    </>
 )}

export default DisplayData;
```

App.js

```
function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
    <DropDown />
    <DisplayData/>
</div>
);}

export default App;
```

How can I pass prop from Dropdown to DisplayData ? or is there something other approach. I want to keep DropDown and DisplayData in separate components.

Comment: Which property are you wanting to sort on? Nothing looks like a _price_ in your data

Comment: @Phil . I corrected. I want based on Age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create some state to hold the sort criteria in `App.js`

   ```js
   const [sortDir, setSortDir] = useState("lowtohigh");
   ```
2. Allow `DropDown` to accept the state setter as a prop

   ```jsx
   const DropDown = ({ setSortDir }) => (
     <select onChange={(e) => setSortDir(e.target.value)}>
       <option value="lowtohigh">Age: Low to High</option>
       <option value="hightolow">Age: High to Low</option>
     </select>
   );
   ```
3. Allow `DisplayData` to accept the sort criteria and create a memo hook to produced the sorted results

   ```jsx
   const record = [
     /*...*/
   ];

   const DisplayData = ({ sortDir }) => {
     const sortedRecords = useMemo(
       () =>
         [...record].sort((a, b) => {
           return sortDir === "lowtohigh" ? a.Age - b.Age : b.Age - a.Age;
         }),
       [sortDir]
     );

     return (
       <table>
         {sortedRecords.map((rec) => (
           <tr key={rec.SR}>{/* etc */}</tr>
         ))}
       </table>
     );
   };
   ```
4. Pass the props into the components

   ```jsx
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <DropDown setSortDir={setSortDir} />
       <DisplayData sortDir={sortDir} />
     </div>
   );
   ```

Comment: I think should be add "record" as a dependancy in useMemo dependancy list

Comment: @AshrafulMijan not if it's declared outside the component